# Image downloaded from web for row in listview smaller as it should be

Tags: java, android, listview, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

I have a lisview, every row is defined in own xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="120dip"
android:padding="6dip" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_below="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cena1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ime"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gumb_klic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ime"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:background="@drawable/call_button"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/razdalja"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ime"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ime"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cena1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cena2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cena1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

In eclipse layout editor it looks like this (ok):

[image]

To download image for imageview (@+id/icon) in every row, i use universal image loader library (https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).
The problem is that when image is downloaded, it is smaller as it should be and also the row is smaller. If i put the same image as downloaded from resources, everything is good until the download finishes, then image gets smaller and also the row.

Is there anything wrong with my layout?

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I think it is because you have set scaleType to "fitCenter" and defined an absolute value for your layout height.  Your image is getting scaled to fit 120dip minus padding.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/icon"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: But i guess there should be the same problem with the same image from local resources ?

Comment: That would seem to be true.  You can check the dimensions of the image after it's downloaded to see if your download class is altering it.  I edited my answer with some code that should force the image to fit your layout even if it's dimensions are being changed.  I haven't tested it, but by aligning your TV to parent bottom and forcing the imageview to fill the space above it should scaled to fill the available space.

Comment: I solved the problem by setting height and width of imageview in dip, so they got scaled according to screen density.